# Query for relational model in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3, one-to-many

I have 3 models named "User","Order","Orders_products". The relations are following:

1. User has many Order
2. Order has many Orders_products

Here are the model's code

> User Model

```
public function order(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
```

> Order Model

```
 public function order_product(){
        return $this-> hasMany('App\Orders_product');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this-> belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

> Orders_products Model

```
public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
```

An user could have multiple orders and all orders could have multiple ordered products. How can i get a particular users all orders along with the ordered products.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$Order = Order::with('order_product')->where(['user_id'=>$id])->get();
```

where `$id` is the `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

User model

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

Order Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}

public function orders_products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Orders_products::class);
}
```

Orders_products

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, $userid is how ever you specify the user id in your app.

```
User::with('order_product.order')->where('id', $usersid)->get();
```

Comment: This returns an empty object.

Comment: $Order = Order::with('order_product')->where(['user_id'=>$id])->get(); this worked for me. Thanks for your appreciation @ATechGuy

Comment: Use the find method